# Añadir nuevo elemento al final de un arreglo de clases C++

Tags: c++

Insertar al inicio funciona a la perfección, pero el insertar al final me tira un break al agregar el primer elemento al arreglo.

**Transporte.h**

```
#include "TipoTransporte.h"
#pragma once

class CTransporte
{
    char* modelo;
    char* color;
    int año;
    CTipoTransporte* tipoT;
    bool seguro;
    bool lunas;
    int llantas;
    char* motor;
    int asientos;
public:

    CTransporte(char* modelo, char* color, int año, CTipoTransporte* tipoT, bool seguro, bool lunas, int llantas, char* motor, int asientos);
    ~CTransporte();
    CTransporte();

    char* getModelo();
    char* getColor();
    int getAño();
    CTipoTransporte* getTipoT();
    bool getSeguro();
    bool getLunas();
    int getLlantas();
    char* getMotor();
    int getAsientos();

    void setModelo(char* value);
    void setColor(char* value);
    void setAño(int value);
    void setTipoT(CTipoTransporte* value);
    void setSeguro(bool value);
    void setLlantas(int value);
    void setMotor(char* value);
    void setAsientos(int value);

};
```

**TipoTransporte.h**

```
#ifndef __TIPOTRANSPORTE_H__
#define __TIPOTRANSPORTE_H__

class CTipoTransporte
{
private:

    bool camionObus;
    float costoSeguro;

public:
    CTipoTransporte();
    CTipoTransporte(bool camionObus, float costoSeguro);
    ~CTipoTransporte();

    bool getCamionOBus();
    float getCostoSeguro();
    void setCamionOBus(bool camionObus);
    void setCostoSeguro(float costoSeguro);

};



#endif // !__TipoTransporte_H__
```

**Arreglo Transporte.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "cstdlib"
#include "Transporte.h"

class CArregloTransporte
{
    CTransporte **arreglo;
    int cant;
public:
    CArregloTransporte();
    ~CArregloTransporte();
    int getCant();
    CTransporte *getElemento(int pos);
    void insertarAlInicio(CTransporte *nuevo);
    void insertarAlFinal(CTransporte* nuevo);
};
```

**Transporte.cpp**

```
#include "Transporte.h"

CTransporte::CTransporte()
{
    modelo = new char[15];
    modelo = (char*)"Nissan";
    color = new char[10];
    color = (char*)"Negro";
    año = 1993;
    tipoT = new CTipoTransporte(true, 800);
    lunas = false;
    llantas = 4;
    motor = new char[15];
    motor = (char*)"4 cilindros";
    asientos = 12;

}

CTransporte::CTransporte(char* modelo, char* color, int año, CTipoTransporte* tipoT, bool seguro, bool lunas, int llantas, char* motor, int asientos)
{
    this->modelo = modelo;
    this->color = color;
    this->año = año;
    this->tipoT = tipoT;
    this->seguro = seguro;
    this->lunas = lunas;
    this->llantas= llantas;
    this->motor = motor;
    this->asientos = asientos;
}
CTransporte::~CTransporte()
{
    delete modelo;
    delete color;
    delete motor;
}


char* CTransporte::getModelo() { return modelo; }
char* CTransporte::getColor() { return color; }
int   CTransporte::getAño() { return año; }
CTipoTransporte* CTransporte::getTipoT() { return tipoT; }
bool  CTransporte::getSeguro() { return seguro; }
bool  CTransporte::getLunas() { return lunas; }
int   CTransporte::getLlantas() { return llantas; }
char* CTransporte::getMotor() { return motor; }
int   CTransporte::getAsientos() { return asientos; }


void  CTransporte::setModelo(char* value) { modelo = value; }
void  CTransporte::setColor(char* value) { color = value; }
void  CTransporte::setAño(int value) { año = value; }
void CTransporte::setTipoT(CTipoTransporte* value) { tipoT = value; }
void  CTransporte::setSeguro(bool value) { seguro = value; }
void  CTransporte::setLlantas(int value) { llantas = value; }
void  CTransporte::setMotor(char* value) { motor = value; }
void  CTransporte::setAsientos(int value) { asientos = value; }
```

**Tipotransporte.cpp**

```
#include "TipoTransporte.h"

CTipoTransporte::CTipoTransporte()
{
    camionObus = true;
    costoSeguro = 400;
}

CTipoTransporte::CTipoTransporte(bool camionObus, float costoSeguro)
{
    this->camionObus = camionObus;
    this->costoSeguro = costoSeguro;
}

CTipoTransporte::~CTipoTransporte()
{
}

bool CTipoTransporte::getCamionOBus() { return camionObus; }
float CTipoTransporte::getCostoSeguro() { return costoSeguro; }
void CTipoTransporte::setCamionOBus(bool value) { camionObus = value; }
void CTipoTransporte::setCostoSeguro(float value) { costoSeguro = value; }
void insertarDondeSea(CTransporte* nuevo,int pos);
```

**ArregloTransporte.cpp**

```
#include "ArregloTransporte.h"

CArregloTransporte::CArregloTransporte()
{
    cant = 0;
    arreglo = new CTransporte*[cant];
}

CArregloTransporte::~CArregloTransporte()
{
    if (arreglo != NULL)
    {
        delete[]arreglo;
    }
}

int CArregloTransporte::getCant()
{
    return cant;
}

CTransporte* CArregloTransporte::getElemento(int pos)
{
    if (pos < cant)
    {
        return arreglo[pos];
    }
}

void CArregloTransporte::insertarAlInicio(CTransporte *nuevo)
{
    CTransporte** aux = new CTransporte*[cant + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
    {
        aux[i + 1] = arreglo[i];
    }

    aux[0] = nuevo;

    cant++;

    if (arreglo != NULL)
        delete[]arreglo;

    arreglo = aux;
}

void CArregloTransporte::insertarAlFinal(CTransporte *nuevo)
{
    CTransporte** aux = new CTransporte*[cant + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
    {
        aux[i] = arreglo[i];
    }


    aux[cant +1] = nuevo;

    cant++;

    if (arreglo != NULL)
        delete[]arreglo;

    arreglo = aux;
}

void CArregloTransporte::insertarDondeSea(CTransporte* nuevo, int pos)
{
    CTransporte** aux = new CTransporte*[cant + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
    {
        if (pos < i)
            aux[i] = arreglo[i];
        else
            aux[i] = arreglo[i + 1];
    }
    aux[pos] = nuevo;
    cant++;
    if (arreglo != NULL)
        delete[]arreglo;
    arreglo = aux;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Transporte.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "ArregloTransporte.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CArregloTransporte* Arreglo1 = new CArregloTransporte();


    bool seguro, lunas, camionObus;
    int año, llantas, asientos, x;
    float costoSeguro;


    do
    {
        cout << "[1] Insertar Datos" << endl;
        cout << "[2] Salir" << endl;

        cin >> x;

        if (x == 1)
        {
            char* modelo = new char[15];
            char* color = new char[10];
            char* motor = new char[15];

            CTransporte* objTransporte1;

            CTipoTransporte* objTipo1;


            cin.ignore();
            cout << "[0] Usa Camion o [1] Usa Bus: ";
            cin >> camionObus;
            cout << endl << "Ingrese el costo del seguro: ";
            cin >> costoSeguro;
            objTipo1 = new CTipoTransporte(camionObus, costoSeguro);

            cin.ignore();
            cout << endl << "Ingrese Modelo: ";
            cin.getline(modelo, 15);
            cout << endl << "Ingrese Color: ";
            cin.getline(color, 10);
            cout << endl << "Ingrese Motor: ";
            cin.getline(motor, 15);
            cout << endl << "Ingrese Año: ";
            cin >> año;
            cout << endl << "Tiene Seguro? Ingrese 0 para NO o 1 para SÍ: ";
            cin >> seguro;
            cout << endl << "Tiene Lunas? Ingrese 0 para NO o 1 para SÍ: ";
            cin >> lunas;
            cout << endl << "Ingrese Cantidad de Llantas: ";
            cin >> llantas;

            cout << endl << "Ingrese Cantidad de Asientos: ";
            cin >> asientos;

            objTransporte1 = new CTransporte(modelo, color, año, objTipo1, seguro, lunas, llantas, motor, asientos);
            Arreglo1->insertarAlFinal(objTransporte1);

        }
    } while (x != 2);

    if (Arreglo1->getCant() != 0)
    {
        cout << "====DATOS INGRESADOS====" << endl;

        for(int i=0;i<Arreglo1->getCant();i++)
        {
            cout << endl << "====Transporte " << i+1 << "====" << endl;
            cout << "Modelo: " << Arreglo1->getElemento(i)->getModelo() << endl;
            cout << "Color: " << Arreglo1->getElemento(i)->getColor() << endl;
            cout << "Año: " << Arreglo1->getElemento(i)->getAño() << endl;
            cout << "Seguro: ";
            if (Arreglo1->getElemento(i)->getSeguro() == 1) { cout << "Seguro: Si tiene seguro" << endl; }
            if (Arreglo1->getElemento(i)->getSeguro() == 0) { cout << "Seguro: No tiene seguro" << endl; }
            //cout << "Seguro: " << Arreglo1->getElemento(i)->getSeguro() << endl;
            cout << "Lunas: ";
            if (Arreglo1->getElemento(i)->getLunas() == 1) { cout << "Si tiene seguro" << endl; }
            if (Arreglo1->getElemento(i)->getLunas() == 0) { cout << "No tiene seguro" << endl; }
            //cout << "Lunas: " << Arreglo1->getElemento(i)->getLunas() << endl;
            cout << "Llantas: " << Arreglo1->getElemento(i)->getLlantas() << endl;
            cout << "Motor: " << Arreglo1->getElemento(i)->getMotor() << endl;
            cout << "Asientos: " << Arreglo1->getElemento(i)->getAsientos() << endl;
        }

    }





    /*CTipoTransporte* obj1;
    obj1 = new CTipoTransporte(true, 800.5);
    CTransporte* obj2;

    obj2 = new CTransporte((char*)("Modelo"), (char*)("Rojo"), 20, obj1, true, true, 4, (char*)("motorX"), 4);

    cout << obj2->getColor();
    */

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código fuente para poder reproducir tu problema?. Lo ideal es que nos proporcionaras un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) en el que pudiéramos reproducir tu problema y así poder ayudarte a solucionarlo. Gracias. PD: A primera vista parece que el código está mal ya que debes agregar el elemento en la posición `cant`.

Comment: falta info. Podrias poner todo el codigo fuente o al menos donde tengas declaradas las variables globales

Comment: Te respondí antes de tu edición mirando el código por encima en la imagen, échale un vistazo cuando puedas a mi respuesta y dime si soluciona tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías cambiar:

```
aux[cant + 1] = nuevo;
cant++;
```

Por:

```
aux[cant] = nuevo;
cant++;
```

O, lo que es lo mismo:

```
aux[cant++] = nuevo;
```

Ya que si no hay elementos (`cant` vale 0) hay que meter el nuevo en el índice 0 y luego incrementar el valor a 1. Si `cant` vale 1, entonces hay que insertar el valor al final, que es el índice 1, y luego incrementarlo a 2.

La comprobación final es absurda ya que tendrías excepciones en tiempo de ejecución si en algún momento `arreglo` vale `NULL`. Esa comprobación deberías haberla hecho al principio para trabajar sólo con `aux`.

Es decir, antes del bucle `for` hacer esto:

```
if (arreglo == NULL) {
  aux[cant++] = nuevo;
  arreglo = aux;
  return;
}
```

O, si no quieres repetir el `arreglo = aux;`, englobar en el `else` el resto hasta él.

---

Respuesta adicional solicitada:

```
void CArregloTransporte::insertarDondeSea(CTransporte* nuevo, int pos)
{
    CTransporte** aux = new CTransporte*[cant + 1];
    int i;
    /* Evitamos problemas por tener un pos > cant
      en ese caso agregaríamos al final */
    for (i = 0; i < pos && i < cant; i++)
    {
        aux[i] = arreglo[i];
    }
    /* Agregamos el elemento en la posición deseada y aumentamos cant */
    aux[i++] = nuevo;
    cant++;
    /* Seguimos con el resto de elementos (si quedan) */
    for (; i < cant; i++)
    {
        aux[i] = arreglo[i - 1];
    }
    if (arreglo != NULL)
        delete[]arreglo;
    arreglo = aux;
}
```

Comment: y si quisiera añadir o eliminar en cualquier posición?
intente con 

void CArregloTransporte::insertarDondeSea(CTransporte* nuevo, int pos)
{
 CTransporte** aux = new CTransporte*[cant + 1];

 for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
 {
  if (pos < i)
   aux[i] = arreglo[i];
  else
   aux[i] = arreglo[i + 1];
 }


 aux[pos] = nuevo;
 cant++;
 if (arreglo != NULL)
  delete[]arreglo;

 arreglo = aux;
}

pero me da error

Comment: Lo siento, no puedo ver correctamente ese código. Añádelo a tu pregunta o crea una nueva y déjame el enlace como comentario aquí para que la revise. Por cierto, recuerda que si te fue de ayuda la respuesta podrías darle un positivo. Si te solucionó el problema deberías marcarla como respuesta correcta para que quede registrada como solucionada.

Comment: Hecho, he agregado mi sugerencia.